# Select from an explicit table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a join on data that does not exist in my database, and never changes.

I want to do:

```
SELECT val, campaign FROM values
LEFT JOIN (SELECT campaign, start, end FROM (
    ('Spring 2104', '2014-05-01', '2014-08-01'),
    ('Winter 2014', '2014-08-01', '2014-12-31')
) as campaign_table ON (
    values.date > campaign_table.start AND
    values.date < campaign_table.end
)
```

Is that possible?  I could create a temporary table, but for what I am trying to do that does not actually work.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: What about this year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `union all` to create the dummy set. This is a viable solution considering there are only a handful of rows in your dummy dataset.

```
SELECT val
    ,campaign
FROM
VALUES
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'Spring 2104' campaign
        ,'2014-05-01' start
        ,'2014-08-01' [end]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Winter 2014'
        ,'2014-08-01'
        ,'2014-12-31'
    ) AS campaign_table ON
VALUES.DATE > campaign_table.start
    AND
VALUES.DATE < campaign_table.[end]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this executing all queries at once:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tempo`( `campaign_name` VARCHAR(100), `from` DATE, `to` DATE ); 
INSERT INTO tempo(campaign_name, `start`, `end`) VALUES ('Spring 2104', '2014-05-01', '2014-08-01'),('Winter 2014', '2014-08-01', '2014-12-31');
SELECT t1.val, t1.campaign, t2.campaign_name FROM `values` t1, `tempo` t2 WHERE t1.date BETWEEN t2.start AND t2.end;
DROP TABLE `tempo`;
```

Also you can make: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE

Try!